# Differentiate Array from Object data type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running an `AJAX` request and it returns a `JSON` formatted response either this:

```
{
    name: "gideon",
    class: "knight",
    ...
}
```

or

```
[
    {
        name: "gideon",
        class: "knight",
        ...
    },
    {
        name: "athena",
        class: "mage",
        ...
    },
    ...
    {
        name: "chris",
        class: "B.O.W Agent",
        ....
    }
]
```

Now, how can I know if the returned type of the call is an `Object` or an `Array` of objects? I need to perform a check for this (plus other checks):

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function(r) {
        if(/* r is an object */) {

        }
        else if(/* r is an array */) {
            // Perform an iteration
        }
    }
});
```

I've performed a `instanceof` and `typeof` operator on these two returned values against `Object` but of course that would be silly because `Array` is a descendant of `Object`, and therefore it will *always* returns `true`.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that this is being returned from a server side component that deals with SOAP? In which case, you will want to fix this on the server side by making sure it's always an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what browsers you need to support.

If you are only supporting "modern" browsers (e.g. IE9 and up), you can use (as @AmmarCSE suggested) the [ES5 `isArray` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
if (Array.isArray(r))
```

If, however, you need to support older browsers (e.g. IE8 on down), you can test the object using `Object.prototype.toString`

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(r) === '[object Array]'
```

Additionally, if you would like to use `Array.isArray` while also supporting older browsers, you can add the following `isArray` polyfill to you javascript, making the `Array.isArray` function available

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**Array.isArray()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) like

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function(r) {
        if(Array.isArray(r)) {
            // Perform an iteration
        }
        else if(/* r is an object */) {
        }
    }
});
```